# Sharing .htaccess files between directories on a server

Tags: htaccess, apache

I have a webserver with thousands of directories.  Some need to be internal only, some need to reference specific IP addresses, some are public.  These `.htaccess` files change from time to time with IP addresses and blocks being added and removed.  Today, each directory (and many subdirectories) have their own `.htaccess` file based on the traffic that's allowed to access it (some subdirectories don't have an `.htaccess` file, they inherit the parent directory's `.htaccess` rules).

Is there a way to organize my directories and `.htaccess` files so that I only have a few main `.htaccess` files and each subdirectory can reference an `.htaccess` based on what access they need?

For example:

```
public .htaccess
restricted .htaccess
private .htaccess

dir1
  subdir1
    use "public .htaccess"
  subdir2
    use "public .htaccess"
    subsubdir1
      use "private .htaccess"
  subdir3
    use "restricted .htaccess"
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903260/how-does-htaccess-recursion-work

Answer (score 1):

You can't do something quite like this at the Apache web server level. However, you could potentially create *symlinks* from `.htaccess` in the subdirectory to the appropriate `.htaccess` file stored elsewhere, so you'd only have one file to update.

If you have access to the server config then you could centralize this and have each "config file" as a separate *include* for the respective `<Directory>` container(s).

However, whether it actually makes sense to do this or not will depend on the specific directives you are using. For instance, mod_rewrite directives are processed relative to the directory where they are contained - so these would need to be written to be independent of the *directory-prefix*.

---

*Aside:* Having too many `.htaccess` files strewn across the filesystem can become difficult to maintain. It may be preferable (depending on the directives) to combine these into a single `.htaccess` file in the root?